# Write a SQL Query to replace values and include all the Dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace, isnull

Well I have this -

```
Table DimDate- Date 
Table Employee-  Id,Name,Points,Date
```

Now the Employee table has points for everyday unless they did not come...so the Date does not have all the Dates entries... I mean for e.g in a week he did not come for 2 days the Employee table has only 5 rows...so I have this dimdate table which has all the dates till 2050 which I want to join with and add Zeros for the dates he does not have points. So I have written this query but does not work -

```
Select E.EmployeeId,D.Date,isNull(E.Points,0) from DimDate D left join Employee E on D.Date between '01-01-2009'and '06-01-2009' where E.EmployeeId=1
```

The above query give multiple dates and I tried group by on Date but does not work.

Comment: So, [Date] is the primary key of the `DimDate` table and this table only has dates (not date and times), correct? Can an Employee row have multiple rows for different days?

Comment: well actually dimdate has other fields but i skipped that..but ya the Date field has unique values of Date and time...and no employee has duplicate rows for a date..will comparing a Datetime and Date give problems??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably dont want to join the two tables on a date range but a date.  Then filter the record set by the date range.  example

```
Select 
  E.EmployeeId,
  D.Date,
  isNull(E.Points,0)  
from DimDate D 
left join Employee E on D.Date = E.Date 
where E.EmployeeId=1 
  AND D.Date Between '01-01-2009'and '06-01-2009'
```

Edited:

```
Select 
  E.EmployeeId,
  D.Date,
  isNull(E.Points,0)  
from DimDate D 
left join Employee E on D.Date = E.Date And E.EmployeeId=1
where D.Date Between '01-01-2009'and '06-01-2009'
```

OR

```
Select 
  E.EmployeeId,
  D.Date,
  isNull(E.Points,0)  
from DimDate D 
left join Employee E on D.Date = E.Date 
where (E.EmployeeId = 1 OR E.EmployeeId is NULL) 
  AND D.Date Between '01-01-2009'and '06-01-2009'
```

Comment: Ya..I got my prb but it still does not return me records till the end date...it only returns me dates that are present in Employee Table..So its returning me only till '04-01-2010'..i guess because i am joining on Date but should not left outer join take all first table dates..?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need a cross join between the dimdates table and the table where your employees are defined.  This will give you a list of records with all employee/date combinations.  Then the result of that needs to be left outer joined to the table that has the employee points records.

Something like:

```
Select CJ.EmployeeId,CJ.Date,isNull(E.Points,0) 
    from (SELECT EmployeeID, D.Date
          from DimDate D CROSS JOIN [EmployeeDefinitionTable] as edt) as CJ
        left outer join Employee E on CJ.Date =E.Date AND CJ.EmployeeId = E.EmployeeId
where CJ.Date between '01-01-2009'and '06-01-2009'
  and E.EmployeeId = 1
```

Where EmployeeDefinitionTable is a table that uniquely lists all employees (or at least their id's for this problem statement).

This also captures employees with no points entries.

The between statement and/or EmployeeId filtering could be moved up into the cross join if it fits your requirements.  It would make the cross join more efficient.